# FREEBSD mysql error table open cache error

Tags: mysql, sql, freebsd

> 2019-03-19 01:43:26 22929 [Warning] Buffered warning: Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 79992 (request: 4294967295)
>
> 2019-03-19 01:43:26 22929 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: table_open_cache: 39915 (requested 524288)

This is my problem in mysql when starting service this is from log. I did not yet google solution because FREEBSD OS

Comment: What are the permissions on file `/usr/local/etc/mysql/my.cnf`?

Comment: 0644 permissions there is it

Comment: Can you try to change it to `0646` and see if it works? You might also want to try `0777`, just to see...

Comment: youre god now working wtf thanks a lot

Comment: Nice! Let me post this as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have hit [this FreeBSD bug](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=209512), which was reported for package `mysql57-server-5.7.12`.

A workaround is to change the permissions of file `/usr/local/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to something like `646` (the key point is that `others` need write permissions).

You can also see this [this FreeBSD forum thread](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/cannot-start-mysql-server-5-7-12-on-freebsd-10-3.56275/) for more information..